# Доставка php получение одго значения?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Как получить значения только одно значение вот такого формата, как на фото? в последнем столбце цена?
используется расчет стоимости и сроков доставки деловых линий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$code = "7800000000000000000000000";
$check = "true";
 $weight = 2;
$data = array(
  "appKey" => "2DFF52B0-8F85-4544-9C8B-5750A283F5DB",
  "derivalPoint" => "7700000000000000000000000",
  "derivalDoor" => true,
  "arrivalPoint" => "{$code}",
  "arrivalDoor" => $check,
  "sizedVolume" => "0.2",
  "sizedWeight" => $weight
);
$json = json_encode($data);
$url = ('https://api.dellin.ru/v1/public/calculator.json');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
curl_close($ch);
print_r("Ответ-".$result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Получили, посмотрели полученное и разобрали что надо.

print_r($obj);

```
stdClass Object
(
    [derival] => stdClass Object
        (
            [terminal] => Москва
            [city] => Москва
            [price] => 400.00
            [discount] => 0.00
            [discountDetails] => Array
                (
                )

            [premium] => 0.00
            [premiumDetails] => Array
                (
                )

            [terminals_express] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 36
                            [name] => Москва Север
                            [address] => 127411, Москва г, Лобненская ул, дом № 18, стр 2
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 283
                            [name] => Москва Восток
                            [address] => 109316, Москва г, Волгоградский пр-кт, дом № 42, корпус 23
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 125
                            [name] => Москва Щелковская
                            [address] => 107553, Москва г, Амурская ул, дом № 1, корпус 3
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 359
                            [name] => Москва Академический
                            [address] => 117312, Москва г, Вавилова ул, 9 А, ст.3
                            [price] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 297
                            [name] => Москва Юг 2
                            [address] => 117545, Москва г, Подольских Курсантов ул, дом № 17, корпус 2
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 119
                            [name] => Москва Марьино
                            [address] => 109651, Москва г, Иловайская ул, дом № 3, стр 1
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 361
                            [name] => Москва Владыкино
                            [address] => 127273, Москва г, Сигнальный проезд, дом № 16, стр 27
                            [price] => 0
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [name] => Москва Запад
                            [address] => 121471, Москва г, Рябиновая ул, дом № 37, стр 1
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 82
                            [name] => Москва Капотня
                            [address] => 140053, Московская обл, Котельники г, Дзержинское ш, дом № 14
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [9] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 124
                            [name] => Москва Войковская 
                            [address] => 125212, Москва г, Адмирала Макарова ул, дом № 2
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [10] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 375
                            [name] => Москва Лефортово
                            [address] => 111024, Москва г, Энтузиастов 1-я ул, дом № 3
                            [price] => 0
                        )

                )

            [terminals] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Москва Север
                            [address] => 127411, Москва г, Лобненская ул, дом № 18, стр 2
                            [id] => 36
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Москва Войковская 
                            [address] => 125212, Москва г, Адмирала Макарова ул, дом № 2
                            [id] => 124
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Москва Восток
                            [address] => 109316, Москва г, Волгоградский пр-кт, дом № 42, корпус 23
                            [id] => 283
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Москва Запад
                            [address] => 121471, Москва г, Рябиновая ул, дом № 37, стр 1
                            [id] => 18
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Москва Капотня
                            [address] => 140053, Московская обл, Котельники г, Дзержинское ш, дом № 14
                            [id] => 82
                            [price] => 100
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Москва Марьино
                            [address] => 109651, Москва г, Иловайская ул, дом № 3, стр 1
                            [id] => 119
                            [price] => 100
                        )
```

Цены:

```
echo $obj->derival->price;
echo $obj->intercity->price;
echo $obj->express->price;
echo $obj->price;
```

Comment: верно лия я ввел результат? http://litesite.extremje.beget.tech/curl.php

Comment: возможно, если вы о тексте в самом низу

Comment: да, потому что цен много и выдает самую большую)

Comment: добавила в ответ цены, если вы об этом. Какая конкретно вам нужна - вам лучше знать.